# Render Component in desired node

Tags: reactjs

I'm using tokbox with opentok-react to create a video chat.

I'm trying to add a component after certain node (aka html element).

On my current application I'm doing something like this to add the element where i needed to (because otherwise it doesn't display on the "bar" I need to).

```
// Creation of audio control
addAudioButton = (targetNode) => {
 var audioButton = document.createElement("button");
 audioButton.id = ("audio" + this.props.subId); 
 audioButton.className = "OT_edge-bar-item OT_mute OT_mode-auto"; 
 audioButton.onclick = this.toggleAudio; 
 audioButton.setAttribute("type","button");
 targetNode.insertBefore(audioButton,targetNode.children[4]);
}
```

And to access the code I'm doing this: (earlier I used document.getElementById but I got many issues because sometimes it "didn't" exist.+

```
// Mute or unmute selected stream
toggleAudio = () => { 
let audioButton = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).children[0].children[6];
if(this.state.audio) { 
    audioButton.classList.add("OT_active");  // Add a class if is clicked to mute let stream = 
this.props.name.includes("Audio") ? this.props.name : this.props.name+"Audio" 
this.props.muteStream(stream); 
} 
else { 
    audioButton.classList.remove("OT_active");  // remove a class if is clicked to unmute let stream = 
this.props.name.includes("Audio") ? this.props.name : this.props.name+"Audio" 
this.props.muteStream(stream); } this.setState(prevState => ({ audio: !prevState.audio })); 
}
```

But this way the component doesn't have a single responsibility, so I want to create another component for the "controls" , but I don't know how to render that component where I need too.

I've tried to do this:

```
<OTSubscriber> <SubControls/> </OTSubscriber>
```

Where OTSubscriber is provided by the package, but SubControls never render (I've checked in the html and the view).

Is there a way to achieve this? maybe something like

```
render.desirednode() {
    return( SUBCONTROLS HERE);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

What I want to happen is to be able to render something like this:

```
<OTSubscriber> <SubControls/> </OTSubscriber>
```

Technically that would work, but it doesn't render anything. With browser tools, the html display nothing. And with react tools it only display a gray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a long time of trying multiple things I came with a solution using Portals. I'm posting this as an answer just in case someone else has a similar problem.

My component where I use a component provided by an npm package looks like this:

```
componentDidMount() {       
        this.subscriber.current.node.classList.add("stream-container")
        if(this.props.hide)
            ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).parentElement.classList.add("Hide");

        if(this.subscriber.current && !this.state.renderControls)
            this.setState({renderControls: true});
    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.error) {
            return(
                <div>{this.state.error}</div>
            );
        }
        else {
            return(
                <Fragment>
                    <OTSubscriber
                    ref={this.subscriber}
                    session={this.props.session}
                    stream={this.props.stream}
                    properties={{
                        subscribeToAudio: this.props.audio,  // set the state of the audio of the stream
                        subscribeToVideo: this.state.video,  // set the state of the video of the stream
                        showControls: false,                 // Hide provided controls to make custom control bar
                        //restrictFrameRate: true,           // let user restrict framerate by prop in index?
                    }}                    
                    onError={this.onError}
                    />
                    {this.state.renderControls ? 
                        <SubscriberControls subscriberRef={this.subscriber} subscriberId={this.props.subscriberId}/> : null
                    }
                </Fragment>
            );            
        }
    }
```

As you can see I'm using refs. So inside the constructor I have this piece of code:

```
this.subscriber = React.createRef();
```

Now, I had to add a new variable to the state because I needed react to enter twice to the render method.

1. For getting the ref of the OTSubscriber.
2. To render the subscriberControls component.

Now my subscriberControls component look like this:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './SubscriberControls.css';

export default class SubscriberControls extends Component {

    render() {
        return ReactDOM.createPortal(
            <Fragment>
                <button 
                    type="button"
                    id={"audio" + this.props.subscriberId}
                    className="OT_edge-bar-item OT_mute OT_mode-auto"
                >                
                </button>
            </Fragment>,
            this.props.subscriberRef.current.node.childNodes[0]      
        );
    }
}
```

This way I achieved to add the subscriberControls as children elements of the OTSubscriber div container.